# Definition of  "throw the gauntlet down"

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions

What is the definition of "throw the gauntlet down"? I googled for it and only got examples where it's used, but no actual definition of the phrase.

Comment: Hint: Don't limit your search to Google.  A search engine will return many results related to pop culture, such as song titles or TV episodes, not necessarily related to definitions and root meanings.  Try [OneLook.com](http://www.onelook.com), which returns results from several online dictionaries.  Moreover, when I googled this expression, I found many links with definitions; for example: [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gauntlet), [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/throw+down+the+gauntlet.html), and [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/throw+down+the+gauntlet).

Comment: what did you exactly google for? I googled: 'definition "throw the gauntlet down"'

Comment: You made your query to restrictive.  Take out the word _definition_.  Simply google: _throw the gauntlet down_ - no quotes.

Comment: @J.R.: That's only relevant in this particular case because the standard expression is *"throw down the gauntlet"*, not *"throw the gauntlet down"*. And those people who use the non-standard word order are likely *not* to be people who are particularly careful with their choice of phrasing, or care much about the origin of the expression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You can google it either way, and the same results will appear.  (I tested that earlier, but didn't feel the need to clarify, since either query would have given him the answer he wanted).  The sole point of my first comment was to point out that the answer was readily available on-line; the sole point of my second was to clarify how I had found the answer so easily, while he did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauntlet_%28glove%29#.22Throw_down_the_gauntlet.22) for this idiom:

> **Throw down the gauntlet:** To "throw down the gauntlet" is to issue a challenge. A gauntlet-wearing knight would challenge a fellow knight
>   or enemy to a duel by throwing one of his gauntlets on the ground. The
>   opponent would pick up the gauntlet to accept the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

This visually wonderful idiomatic expression means to challenge someone to an argument or some kind of intellectual combat or dual. Here is an example: "Annie has thrown down the gauntlet again and asked her friends to take on her views."

Comment: It's commonly used of political ultimata or upcoming sporting events. In the former, arguments are what you have when you *aren't* issuing ultimata, and in the latter intellectual prowess is not the most vital.